# Configure Fabric in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

i'm trying to configure fabric in my iOS application

I have idea that we need to enter ***api key*** in application and have to download **fabric' framework**. The problem is i don't know how to get APi key.

I've created account on fabric, but don't know **how to proceed**. Unable to see ***Dashboard*** over there. Kindly help me how to do it. I'm stuck on this screen (screen shot below).

I've added xcode sdk and can see fabric app in my mac. But what about 3rd step. i think it's the main step and may be i will be able to get api key from here. but how to navigate to that.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Did you launch the fabric app?

Comment: can you share the link of desktop app? @Tometoyou

Comment: Click the link where it says "download and install the app", that should take you to the right place to download it

Comment: "this xcode project does not have any Mac or iOS targets" getting this error now (in fabric app)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was the issue with project. i cloned it from another one and deleted fabric Api key from info.plist. Something was causing issue.

**How i fixed it:**
i created a new project. Made account on fabric. Installed its xcode plugin. The plugin gave me the option to choose project, i selected mine. Afterwards, it guided me step by step i.e adding run script etc and added fabric api keys in my info.plist on its own. Now it's working fine.

i was worried that why *dashboard* is not displayed on fabric.io, it was no issue at all. Once i configured fabric in my project, the dashboard appeared on fabric.io as well

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add fabric to your app is via the desktop app, Click on "New app" and follow the instructions

Comment: Desktop app for mac? link please

Comment: https://ssl-download-crashlytics-com.s3.amazonaws.com/fabric/builds/Fabric-latest.zip

Comment: i'm getting this error now, "this xcode project does not have any Mac or iOS targets" (in fabric' app)

Comment: What target are you building to ?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it. 
i'm working on a TVOS (iOS 9.1) and iOS application (iOS 8.3). Using cocopods and have added fabric using pods as well.
When i open fabric app and select my project, i get this error

Comment: You don't need an API key. Fabric uses the app bundle id. Just use CodoaPods to get the lib and call Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]). Also remember to add the dSYM upload script to build settings.

Comment: @Tapani, thanks, but in another project of mine, i can see the dash board etc. why i'm unable to see it in this case. i think i'm missing something

Comment: If you have built your app and it still does not appear the bundle id probably is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. let me check it.